# How to create Tablet layout in eclipse for android

Tags: android, mobile, tablet

I am trying to create a variation of my handheld device layout to a tablet version. I initially chose one of my screens and in the Layout editor i chose qualifiers for 7" tablet of w1024dp and landscape. now it auto generated a folder called layout_w1024dp-land and made a copy of file i was using. issue is when i install on my kindle I get the original layout for mobile device and not the tablet layout.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) you will see that you are doing it right, but that devices that are pre Android-3.2 (including the Kindle which is a 2.X variant) will not recognize that folder:

> However, this won't work well on pre-3.2 devices, because they don't
>   recognize sw600dp as a size qualifier, so you still have to use the
>   xlarge qualifier as well. So, you should have a file named
>   res/layout-xlarge/main.xml which is identical to
>   res/layout-sw600dp/main.xml. In the next section you'll see a
>   technique that allows you to avoid duplicating the layout files this
>   way.

More info on how to deal with the issue if you follow the link.